# ajax/jquery disables links after submit

Tags: jquery, validation, hyperlink

i am working on this form.
i am using lightbox and dhtml fade effects.
the content in my lightbox is a form. i am using jquery to validate the form.
once the form is submitted, i redirect a user back to a thank you page.
what i am noticing is that, once all the above events has taken place, i cannot click anywhere on my screen, all the links/buttons are sort of disable. i need to press F5 to refresh the page to be able to click anywhere on the page again?

is this happening because i am using jquery validation and an events already took place, how do i resolve this as i am a newbie to jquery. thanks

Comment: please give us some code

Comment: so i click on this link: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:fireMyPopup()">email</a> 
then a lightbox/dhtml fade effect box comes. and that box has a form. once the form is submitted, i display thank you on the same box. the user can click on the close button to close the box. after all this is done, a user cannot click anywhere on the screen. the page becomes static, until i have to refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery to click on the links you likely are using this right now:

```
$("#yourdiv").click(function(){
    // your function here
});
```

when you update the content with javascript those links won't work anymore. for them to keep working you need to use the live function:

```
$('#yourdiv').live("click", function(){
    // your function here
});
```

I think this is your problem since I'm not completely sure what happens after you submit your form (maybe you left some details out)

Comment: so i click on this link: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:fireMyPopup()">email</a> 
then a lightbox/dhtml fade effect box comes. and that box has a form. once the form is submitted, i display thank you on the same box. the user can click on the close button to close the box. after all this is done, a user cannot click anywhere on the screen. the page becomes static, until i have to refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a little bit like the lightbox popup hasn't closed properly, maybe the background that makes your popup modal isn't being removed.